# Multiple JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I need help with making a decision on parsing. I need to do JSON parsing. The way i was doing it was with one generic style network call using Volley and 1 massive switch case that would go to the relevant parse. I would add a String to the method called source so I knew what parsing needs to be done.

Initial call

```
private void getHomeScreen(){
   networkCall(
            url,         //Url used to make the call
            homeScreen);  //The source of the parsing
}
```

The response once the network call has completed sending it to the parser

```
onResponse{
   parser(
         jsonFile, //Response JSON file
         source);  //passing the String that had the source of the parser
}
```

The Parser method that sends the correct response to the correct parser

```
private void parser(JSONObject, String source){
 // the one massive switch case sending the HomeScreen to the relevant parser
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? there must be!

Thanks

Comment: pass unique `Response.Listener` for each type of request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would look at `Gson` for android. `Gson` is a library that can easily parse JSON. So there is no need to make your own parsers. With `Gson` you can make model classes and all the parsing will be done for you.

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not know that it does its own Parsing! That will make it much better and easier!